# Dynamically get field of object in dart

Tags: reflection, dart

How do I dynamically get a field from an object instance?

I have this code:

```dart
var reflection = reflect(this);
InstanceMirror field = reflection.getField(new Symbol(fieldName));
```

When I print the variable `field` I get `InstanceMirror on <'value of field'>` so it's all there,... but how to actually get the value?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Once you get your [InstanceMirror](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.0/dart-mirrors/InstanceMirror-class.html) representing the field, simply call [`field.reflectee`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.0/dart-mirrors/InstanceMirror/reflectee.html).

Comment: Oh.. you were 10 seconds faster than me :) Thanks.

Comment: Updated links https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.0/dart-mirrors/InstanceMirror-class.html and https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.0/dart-mirrors/InstanceMirror/reflectee.html

Answer (score 1):

I found it. The actual value is in the InstanceMirror `.reflectee` property.